# Python: How to inherit and override a method having a queryset?

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have 2classes `A` and `B` :

```
class A(ListView):
        model=Model_name
        def get_queryset(self):
            instance = self.get_user_by_credential(...)
            if instance:
                model_instance = self.model.objects.get(id=instance.id)
                some_objects= self.Model_name.objects.filter(content_id=5, object_id=model_instance.id)
                return some_objects
            return []



class B(A,UserObject):
      model=B_model
      param='foo'
      def get_queryset(self):
            instance = self.get_user_by_credential(...)
            if instance:
                model_instance = self.model.objects.get(id=instance.id, param=param)
                some_objects= Model_name.objects.filter(content_id=5, object_id=model_instance.id)
                return some_objects
            return []
```

the difference between the 2 classes is only the `param` in the queryset of `B`

How can I override the method of the parent class `A` and add a parameter to the queryset of the child class `B` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you're getting a B_model object with the ID of a user object. How do you know they will have the same IDs?

Comment: I have many user profiles ..I have to get the model_object of the current user who is active

Comment: To get the model object of the currently logged in user, use `request.user`; otherwise you have a security hole where anyone can see other user's data by simply trying different IDs in the query string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make a `get_model_instance` method and then use that inside the A implementation so that you can remove the implementation in B.

```
def get_model_instance(self):
    instance = self.get_user_by_credential(...)
    if instance:
         return self.model.objects.get(id=instance.id)
    return None

def get_model_instance(self):
    instance = self.get_user_by_credential(...)
    if instance:
         return self.model.objects.get(id=instance.id, param=param)
    return None
```

or as suggested by Daniel Roseman

```
def get_model_instance(self, instance):
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Bur the `instance.id` is from the `if .. else` statement . I can't make it in a different method .

Comment: @pietà - Move that to the get instance too

Comment: Or keep it in `get_queryset`, but pass it to `get_model_instance` as a parameter.